# Getting value from Moodle php array?

Tags: php, arrays, moodle

I need to the the id values (21,22,23) from this array:

```
Array ( [21] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 21 ) [22] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 22 ) [23] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 23 ) )
```

`array_shift` wont work and i cant use `$myarray[21]` as i need it to work for all values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ids = array_keys($array)
```

Or

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
  $ids[] = $item->id;
}
```